# How do I use a JavaScript variable in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I am trying to use a JS variable in CSS.

In JavaScript it's:

```
var bodybg = "#fff"
```

And in CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: bodybg;
}
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate style with JavaScript.

For example:

```
<p id="p2">Hello World!</p>

<script>
 var bodybg = '#fff';
 document.getElementById("p2").style.color = bodybg;
</script>
```

Comment: Who upvotes a "you can not." when there is already a duplicate vote which shows you can?

Comment: Can I change color from gradient ? Css gradient

Comment: background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);

Answer (score 0):

This change body background color

```
var bodybg = "#fff";
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = bodybg;
```